# Any alternative to MLab for learning using dev and prod database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

If I understand well, MLab is now MongoDB Atlas. MLab is no longer accepting new accounts.

And MongoDB Atlas don't allow dev databases to do something like this:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
module.exports = {
    mongoURI: 'mongodb://user:userpass@dsxxxx.mlab.com:xxxx/myproyect-prod'
}
} else {
    module.exports = {
        mongoURI: 'mongodb://localhost/myproyect-dev'
    }
}
```

Any alternative to MLab for learning using dev and prod database?

Comment: As long as you have the correct MongoDB connection strings this logic should work with any deployments. You haven't included a MongoDB Atlas example, but note that you need to include `?ssl=true&authSource=admin"` in your connection string (SSL is required and you must authenticate against the admin database). See [Connect via Driver](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/) in the Atlas docs for more details.

Comment: @Stennie thanks but MondoDB Atlas don´t allow prod databases if I understand well. That's why I was asking for any alternatives like MLab before

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a prod database? MongoDB Atlas has a [free tier](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/atlas-free-tier-setup/) similar to mLab (512 MB of storage, shared RAM) but with the latest version of MongoDB server (mLab only offered 3.6) and better security (TLS/SSL is required; mLab only offered that on dedicated plans). In general I wouldn't recommend running a production application on a free tier, but if the [resource limits](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/) fit your use case perhaps you can get away with doing so.

Comment: @Stennie thanks for the reply, I will try to use for learning from a tutorial.